# Babel with Vue CLI and express JS - Unexpected token export when exporting a class

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, babeljs, vue-cli

I'm facing an issue when exporting a class in expressJS with ES6 syntax. 
My project is a Vue CLI project, with an express JS server.

To convert the express server in ES5 I'm using this script when starting it:

```
nodemon ./server/index.js --exec babel-node --presets @babel/preset-env
```

It is working fine until I'm trying to export a class.

```
class ErrorHandler extends Error {
    constructor(statusCode, message) {
        super(statusCode, message)

        this.statusCode = statusCode
        this.message = message
    }
}

const handleError = (err, res) => {
    if (!err.statusCode) err.statusCode = 500 // Sets a generic server error status code if none is part of the error
    const { statusCode, message } = err
    res.status(statusCode).json({
        status: "error",
        statusCode,
        message
    })
}

export{
    ErrorHandler,
    handleError
}
```

This piece of code will failed, and return this error:

```
export default function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\Romain\Documents\Developement\projector\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\Users\Romain\Documents\Developement\projector\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Romain\Documents\Developement\projector\server\helpers\error.js:10:47)
```

I tried to delete the handleError function, and it was still not working, but when I tried to delete the ErrorHandler class, everything was fine, so it has to come from the class.

I'm new to Node js AND babel, and after all my research I cannot find what the problem is.

**Update** Here is the package.json

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "server": "nodemon ./server/index.js --exec babel-node --presets @babel/preset-env"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bulma": "^0.7.5",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.16.2",
    "mongodb": "^3.3.2",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/node": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.10.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.10.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.2.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
}
```

And babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app',
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try this: `nodemon --exec babel-node ./server/index.js` and put preset in a `.babelrc` file in the root dir. `{"presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]}`

Comment: I added the presets in the babel.config.js generated by vue CLI, but I still have the same issue

Comment: Okay! Can you update the question with `package.json` or do u have all the babel packages installed: `cli` `core` `node`

Comment: I updated the question. All babel packages are included into vue-cli ( I guess... ). Exept for babel-node and preset-env that I had to install manually. ( thanks for your help btw. Appreciate :) )